# Shadow effect of TextView in Android Studio doesn't work

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

I'm new to Android Studio and I need help with putting a shadow to my TextView. I read other topics on it and I think my code is correct. Which would mean that I might have some problem with the IDE, maybe a setting I missed or something. This is my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.android.giphy.MainActivity">

    <pl.droidsonroids.gif.GifImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/lope3"
        android:background="#000102"
        android:id="@+id/gifImageView"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:text="@string/main"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:padding="20dp"
        android:fontFamily="monospace"
        android:textSize="32sp"
        android:shadowColor="#f4e402"
        android:shadowRadius="5.0"
        android:shadowDy="5.0"
        android:shadowDx="5.0" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/greeting"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:padding="20dp"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:fontFamily="monospace"
        android:textSize="32sp"    />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Unfortunately the text shadow doesn't appear. I tested it on a tablet and a phone both running Android 6.0. Any thoughts?

Thanks.

Comment: what theme are you using for your activity  ?

Comment: I'm using this theme: <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">

Comment: Well your code is correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, thank you guys for your contributions. I played around with the code and put a larger value to radius added a black background to the TextView and voila...the shadow!

Answer (score 0):

you can try this in run time

```
TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview);
text.setShadowLayer(1, 0, 0, Color.RED);
```

Comment: I tried this but it did not work. I added it in the java > come.example.android.giphy > MainActivity in the onCreate method.